# Figure caption is way too low (using LaTeX file images)

Tags: gnuplot

I'm uploading an image I created with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) on to my document using;

```
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\begin{center}
\input{plot.tex}
\caption{Graph caption}
\label{fig4}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

The problem is it looks like;

http://postimg.org/image/j4i4oylx9/

The figure caption is way too low. I can't figure out whether this is an issue with LaTeX or gnuplot. I've tried to figure out ways to reduce the margin on gnuplot but to no avail.

How do I decrease the gap from the picture and caption?

If anyone needs, this is my gnuplot stuff;

```
 set terminal latex
 set out 'plot.tex'
 set termoption dash

 set xrange [0:20]
 set yrange [-1:1]

 unset colorbox


 plot besj1(x)  ls 1 title '$J_1(x)$',\
 besy1(x)  ls 11 title '$Y_1(x)$',  \

set label 5 '$J_1(x)$' at 2, 0.7
set label 6 '$Y_1(x)$' at 4.5, 0.45
set size 1, 0.75

unset key
set out
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It looks like a suboptimal bounding box for your figure but without a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Why do you not use `eps` or `pdf` terminal for graphics output of `gnuplot`?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like gnuplot's `latex` terminal introduces some empty space around the plot. You can see it with

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{\input{plot.tex}}
\caption{Graph caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I don't know how to suppress this margin within gnuplot (long time without using it ;-)) but you can adjust it from `plot.tex`.

This file starts with

```
% GNUPLOT: LaTeX picture
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.240900pt}
\ifx\plotpoint\undefined\newsavebox{\plotpoint}\fi
\sbox{\plotpoint}{\rule[-0.200pt]{0.400pt}{0.400pt}}%
\begin{picture}(1500,900)(0,0)
\sbox{\plotpoint}{\rule[-0.200pt]{0.400pt}{0.400pt}}%
```

`(1500,900)` is figure's top right corner and `(0,0)` its bottom left corner. Change `(0,0)` to `(0,40)`, save `plot.tex`, compile again and will get:

[image]

If you have to do a lot of figures like this, I'd suggest selecting another terminal (eps, pdf, tikz) or using `pgfplots` which can call gnuplot to compute Bessel functions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to plot it via `pgfplots` with `addplot` and `gunplot` capability. Then use of `caption` to adjust the gap between the figure and the caption.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm,papersize={12cm,10cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
%\input{plot.tex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=10cm,
height=5cm,ymin=-1,ymax=1,
xmin=0,xmax=20,
]
\addplot[color=yellow,
solid, line width=1.0pt,
domain=0:20, samples=400]
gnuplot {besj1(x)};
\node at (axis cs: 6,0.5){$Y_1(x)$};
\addplot[color=blue,
solid, line width=1.0pt, restrict y to domain=-1:1,
domain=0:20,samples=400]
gnuplot {besy1(x)};
\node at (axis cs: 2,0.7){$J_1(x)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Graph caption}
\label{fig4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```