# Need serious help with epslatex gnuplot terminal in beamer!

Tags: beamer, gnuplot

Well, I'm using this to generate my `graph.tex` and `graph.eps` files from `gnuplot`:

```
set terminal epslatex input color colortext size 11.6cm, 8.5cm solid linewidth 2
```

But when I use

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
\input{graph}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
```

the text is centered but the image is not (it is a little bit up and to the right). Here's what it produces

[image: What I'm getting]

I already tried changing the order of the `center` and `figure` environments and putting the `[htp]` option instead of just `[h]`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Probably, the margins of your gnuplot image aren't symmetric. Use `\fbox{\input{graph}}` to see the margins. And you don't need to use a floating environment with beamer. Just use `\begin{center}\input{graph}\end{center}` or a `minipage`.

Comment: OK. I removed the figure environment and left jus the center. I also put the `\fbox` preceding the `\input`. What I see is a margin that seems to be the page margin and the margins of the gnuplot image are deslocated with respect to these (they are a little up and to the right)... Thanks very much for your attention!

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23596518/2604213 for reducing the white space.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176217/1952

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to a wrong option passed to a script not connected to TeX and friends.

Comment: In my case the misalignment was fixed by the answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/344190/60337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

The problem was when I was using `ps2pdf` to create a pdf version of `graph.eps`, I was using

`ps2pdf -dEPScrop graph.eps graph.pdf`

instead of

`ps2pdf -dEPSCrop graph.eps graph.pdf`

(Damn you, capital c!)

The last one gave me the correct plot!

Anyway, thanks very much for the comments guys :)