# Misplaced images when run dvi to pdf

Tags: dvipdfmx, dvipdf

I compile with latex and when I run dvi to pdf the images are misplaced (see atach)[image]. Instead when I run dvi to ps to pdf the images are corrected place. 
please, any person can help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{macros_article} % twocolumn

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{psfig}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*} \centerline{\includegraphics[width=11.5cm]{Figure2_con276}} \caption{Sequence of steps to update a ``cloud'' }\label{fig1} \end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We'll need a full example: are you passing the `dvipdfmx` option to `graphicx`, for example?

Comment: Yes, I am, but the problem is still. I changed my computer, but I have the same version of the programs.

Comment: @user121170 Please edit in an example document!

Comment: I've edited in the example: I don't see the `dvipdfmx` option here! Add it to the `\documentclass` line: `\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}`.

Comment: Not directly related, by `\centerline` is a TeX not a LaTeX command: you really should be using `\centering` inside your `figure`.

Comment: thank you for your help. It looks good the pdf. Now, the images in the dvi are misplaced. Incredible!!

Answer (score 4):

The standard 'guess' that is used by the `graphics` package (and which propagates to `graphicx`, *etc.*) is that when LaTeX is called in DVI mode the `dvips` driver will be used, *i.e.* DVI -> PS -> PDF. When one is using the `dvipdfmx` route (*i.e.* DVI -> PDF), the instructions in the SVI file about graphics needs to be different. Thus you need to override the guess with

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
```

or similar.